# How do I return to the title screen in my window-based iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a window-based iPhone app that is a simple game. In the window, I add a subview, which is my title page. On the title page, there is a "play" button. When the user presses the "play" button, I add a subview to my title page view, that is the game itself. When the game is finished, I want to return to the title page. How do I do this? I tried using `removeFromSuperview`, but it doesn't do anything!

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: RemoveFromSuperView must work. Can you show some of your code here ?

Comment: This is my GameOver function, inside my UIViewController: (I am using MonoTouch, so the code is C#):

Comment: public void GameOver()
{
    this.View.RemoveFromSuperView();
}

Comment: I have debugged to verify that this code is run, but after it is run, the Game view remains on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your views inside UIViewControllers and those UIViewControllers inside a UINavigationController, then use the UINavigationController handle that for you.

Comment: My views are already inside UIViewControllers. Do I have to use a UINavigationController to do this? It seems so simple!

Answer (score -1):

I think `removeFromSuperview` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Oops that is what I meant in my post, I made a typo. I did try removeFromSuperview, and nothing happens!